# Time zone with mongooseJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model which stores the current date of each record, but the date is being saved for another time zone,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),   
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var TicketSchema = new Schema({

  creado:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
ticketId: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Id del ticket es obligatorio'
},
tiempo: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Tiempo invertido en el ticket es obligatorio'
},
tipo: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Tipo del ticket es obligatorio'
},
sendto: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Campo SendTo del ticket es obligatorio'
},
creador: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
}
```

});

mongoose.model('Ticket',TicketSchema); strong text

Comment: can you specify what did you try to save and what actually got saved? Also, your code that you tried to save?

Comment: Please post the actual issue here with details. In general you would want to store the timestamp in epoch time. That ways any application accessing it can relate to their timezone easily.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB always stores date in GMT timezone. So you need not worry about the time difference across timezones. For presenting this date in UI you can retrieve this date from DB and convert it into whatever timezone you want.

Comment: That is my case, the database stores the date in that format GMT, apology in that case what would be the best way to change the date on the front end, I'm using angularjs in the front end,  I need the format for Centro America "Costa rica" if is possible

Comment: use moment.js library. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100124/angularjs-display-timestamp-date-in-different-timezones